# Leveling in Elder Tale

Tags: log-horizon

First of all, I'd like to say, that I **did not** see *Log Horizon 2nd season*, so if answer should contain any spoilers, just direct me to watch *Log Horizon 2*.

Shiroe explained, that new datadisk was released pretty much the same time as the [Apocalypse](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Catastrophe) happened. That datadisk, apart from others, increased level cap to 100. There also were guilds, which were buying EXP pots from such bad guilds as [Hamelin](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Hamelin) in order to progress faster. But, in the whole season 1, I did not notice anyone having level higher than 90. Is getting EXP such slow (past 90) in Elder Tale, or am I missing something? I did not even see anyone's EXP bar, but leveling is definitely possible, since Minori's team managed to get few levels in main class.

Comment: People definitely leveled past 90 even in season one (though nobody hit 100). If I can dredge up some screenshots, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @senshin That would be great!

Comment: You know, I might be wrong about that. The only high-level player whose stats screen we see towards the end of season 1 is Shiroe (in the episode where he makes Rundel into an adventurer), and he's still level 90 at that point. But in season 2, you do see people with levels above 90. Leveling past 90 is possible; it's just slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Elder Tales was first released, the maximum attainable level was 40. It wwas gradually increased throughout the expansion packs. Before the Catastrophe, the maximum attainable level was 90.

According to the [Wiki](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page),

> With the release of the Homesteading the Noosphere expansion pack, the maximum level cap rose to 100. However, this change probably only applies to the Yamato server, as the other servers were not yet implemented with the expansion pack when the Catastrophe struck.

It is unclear to exactly how many servers was this expansion pack applied which implies that not all the players trapped inside the game have the ability to grow their levels beyond 90. But the expansion pack does apply to the Yamato server. Meaning the players in Log Horizon can definitely level up beyond 90. It can be concluded that leveling up beyond 90 is just very very slow and requires a lot of EXP points.

Moreover, it kind makes sense too that we don't see any characters above level 90 since none of them are actually seen grinding for high level monsters. Shiroe's gang was at doing that at least before Shiroe started working for the Round Table Conference. But they had no time for that after Shiroe tried to bring everyone together. They have become more "politics oriented". Trying to set up proper living system in Akihabara, the round table conference and all. None of them is really going all out for EXP. So it seems only logical that none of them were able to accumulate enough EXP points yet.

Here's a link to the [level system](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Level) resource from the Wiki.